# Glue crawler not creating table for SQL Server data source

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am creating a Glue Crawler to crawl some on-premise SQL server database tables. I am using the below SQL server database connection syntax - is this correct? The crawler is not throwing any error but it is not adding any tables. I understand Include path details need to be case-sensitive. I have taken care of that and yet the crawler doesn't add the table.

> SQL Server connection :
>   jdbc:sqlserver://ipaddress:1433;databaseName=test1
>
> Include path: test1/dbo/%

Tried this too in the crawler but still no table was added by the crawler
Include path:   test1/dbo/table1

Comment: Could it be that you created "test1" as a system database? Glue will not pickup system databases. Wildcards at the end will work fine, so "test1/dbo/%" should work fine assuming that "test1" is the name of the database (not the database instance), and that it is not a system database. Feel free to share more details if you need help, I have this working for me just fine.